# LARAVEL - MULTIPLE FILE UPLOAD DOESNT WORK AND RETRIEVING

Tags: laravel, file-upload

When I click on submit, it's only storing last selected file where it suppose to store all the images and how to retrieve those files? Any suggestion or example? Do I need to have different attributes for multiple files?

**Controller**

```php
        if (is_array($request->carEvidence)) {
            foreach ($request->carEvidence as $key => $file) {
                $destinationPath = public_path('image/');
                $profileImage = $key . "-" . date('YmdHis') . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $file->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
                $post['carEvidence'] = "$profileImage";
            }
        }
```

**Views**

```php
   <input type="file" name="carEvidence[]" multiple>
```

MYSQL
https://ibb.co/9sPLw8C

File Input
https://ibb.co/VHkxRwc

Comment: can you put your `<form>` tag code here?

Comment: @Karan here's my code   {!! Form::open(['action' => 'internalAuditController@store', 'method' => 'internalAudit', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

Comment: method="post" is a correction in your form tag

Comment: Do i need to use explode or something which detect the last format for the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing multiple files in array, so you have to use loop to retrieve all the files in controller.. something like

```php
if (is_array($request->carEvidence))
{
    foreach ($request->carEvidence as $key => $file) {
        $destinationPath = public_path('image/');
        $profileImage = $key."-".date('YmdHis') . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
        // code to save in your db table
    }
}
```

Comment: can you get all files or array of files in controller? check it using `dd($request->all());`

Comment: <input type="file" name="carEvidence[]" multiple> Is this correct? Can i store all the doc and image in one attribute?

Comment: @Steven yes it is correct multiple attribute, name with array

Comment: Got an error after selected pdf and png files! Whoops! There were some problems with your input.

The car evidence must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, zip, pdf.

Comment: i think you are validating some extension, so please verify that first or remove for temporary

Comment: After removed the required in controller. It was able to store in mysql but only the last selected file(1 file) :(